# How to be certain my motherboard is dead

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, fan

After searching, I haven't found a question matching my scenario, which is: Connected new power supply (old one started making a very strange sound and I assumed it was dying or dead); hit power-on button and nothing happens (except power-led is on) - cpu fan off, power-supply fan off and, of course no boot-up.  Tested the new PSU (clip/4&5 pin test) - fan spun - it is fine. Can I assume under this scenario that the motherboard is definitely dead (murdered by the old PSU, of course), or could there be some other cause of this behavior?

[2022-06-10 8am CDT] Apologies to mitts and the others who responded - I should have given a more complete background: I did the same pin test on the old PSU - it's dead. I ordered the new PSU because the old one was making very strange sounds when I last started the system up, so I shut it down immediately (without knowing if the rest of the system was OK at that point). I just took a close look at all of the capacitors (after googling what to look for) - as far as I can tell, they all look fine: all the tops are flat, no signs of leakage or corrosion that I can detect. The RAM looks fine to me - I don't think any of the other motherboards I have are compatible so I don't think I can test it. As I'm sure you can tell, I'm pretty electronics-illiterate. I haven't taken the CPU out to look at it, but I'm not sure what I would look for. It's a backup file server - no PCI cards. No DVD drive. I haven't tested the (4) hard drives yet. I don't have any electronic equipment, such as a voltage meter.

Comment: Did you recently disconnect your processor?

Comment: Take it to a repair shop and get it tested.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be certain your motherboard is dead then place it in a vat of acid. Hydrochloric is good and available in reagent grade from your friendly local industrial supplier or local meth lab.

Based on the information given - you did not test for any particular voltage on any rails of the new PSU; you did not test for any actual failure of the old PSU; you do not mention CPU or RAM; you don't mention dismantling anything to look for blown caps; you don't mention any PCI cards, case, audio, optical, HDD connections made to the motherboard...
and given that the little green light is on...yes, there could be some other cause for that behaviour. HTH.